# How install the R lodown package

Tags: r

good afternoon!

I'm trying to install the lodown package and I'm not sure if this error it's version or permission issue.

Could you help me decipher this mistake?

Thankful,
Ricardo Tavares.

## ---------------------------------------------------------

```
> install.packages("devtools")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/rtavares/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.fiocruz.br/src/contrib:
  não foi possível abrir o arquivo de destino 'C:\Users\rtavares\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8qzmlU\file28505e3d335a', motivo 'No such file or directory'
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib:
  não foi possível abrir o arquivo de destino 'C:\Users\rtavares\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8qzmlU\file2850182945b1', motivo 'No such file or directory'
Error in gzfile(file, mode) : não é possível abrir a conexão
Além disso: Warning messages:
1: package ‘devtools’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3) 
2: In gzfile(file, mode) :
  não foi possível abrir o arquivo comprimido 'C:\Users\rtavares\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8qzmlU/libloc_196_5b9aa1bc.rds', motivo provável 'No such file or directory'

> library(devtools)

> install_github("ajdamico/lodown")

Installation failed: Failed to open file C:\Users\rtavares\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8qzmlU\file285067ec2b4.
```

Comment: I don't know if you've solved it by now, but the failure of `devtools` contradicts the next two lines showing that it is actually available. Perhaps you have a version already? Regardless, one way I get that final error is when Windows (or my antivirus) smartly purges my temp directory, which R does not automatically recreate. In this case (and this case *only*, since the dirname is random), a simple `dir.create("/Users/rtavares/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp8qzmlU")` might suffice. (There are plenty of other reasons to get that error, so I'm just taking a stab.)